# Pivotal Gemfire: Cannot create GemfireCache; NoSuchMethodError Jgroups

Tags: spring, gemfire, jgroups, spring-data-gemfire

My system currently uses a gemfire cache and uses the io.pivotal.gemfire dependencies. Two of the dependencies, geode-core and geode-management both use org.jgroups (jgroups) as a runtime dependency. Currently I am using version 9.10.13 of the io.pivotal.gemfire dependencies (geode-core, geode-wan, geode-management etc. (see code snippet below)) and version 3.6.14.Final of jgroups.

Due to a vulnerability in the current version of jgroups, I want to upgrade to a newer version (any in version 4 would be sufficient but the newer the better ([versions](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jgroups/jgroups))). The problem I am having is that when I attempt to upgrade to a newer version (3.6.17 or newer), I get the following error when attempting to start-up the cache server:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jgroups.View.<init>(Lorg/jgroups/ViewId;Ljava/util/List;)V
    at org.apache.geode.distributed.internal.membership.gms.messenger.JGroupsMessenger.installView(JGroupsMessenger.java:459) ~[geode-membership-9.10.13.jar:?]
```

When I actually go to investigate the issue, it looks as though it is referencing a line where the View class constructor was changed to take in a "Collection" instead of a "List", which seemed like a strange error since a List is a Collection.

I have tried using different combinations of jgroups and gemfire going up to 4/5 and 9.10.17 respectively without success. If anyone has any recommendations on how to move past (solve) this jgroups vulnerability while using a gemfire cache it would be much appreciated. Also, is there a table that lists gemifre versions vs. supported versions of jgroups?

Answer (score 1):

Was able to get in contact with VMware Tanzu. All 9.* versions of gemfire require jgroups 3.6.14.Final. The new version of gemfire (10.*) which is currently in beta, is supposed to remove all dependencies on jgroups.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).